# Speech Recognizer in App inventor doesnt work to strings

Tags: button, speech-recognition, app-inventor

I created a basic app (to practice).

So, i created one with this one:

[Test App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoZSP.png)
[image]

So, when the button "habla" it's clicked the recognizer starts. After that i do a condition that compares the text obtained in the recognizer with the word "day". And if the word is same the player1 starts.

Now, i change the word "day" to "day tripper" and doesn't works. So how i can do to the recognizer detects string or more than 1 word?

Comment: you might want to display the recognized text in a label to find out, what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

The number one skill involved in debugging is problem finding, and the problem you have stated for this is

> I change the word "day" to "day tripper" and it doesn't work.

What you need to do, then, is change the logic flow from if mus.result = "day" to if mus.result includes "day".

One way to make this happen would be to initialize a new variable (name doesn't matter) as an empty list. Then, inside of the mus.AfterGettingText control block, set the variable to split at spaces mus.result. Split at spaces is a text function that creates a list of the words in a string.

Then, all you need to do is check each element in the list to see if it is the word "day". This way, the input can be any sentence with the word "day" and player1 would still start.